# GitHub Actions fails to commit due to permission denied

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to run an action in GitHub to release a jar on Maven Central.

The action seems that fails to commit on the repository the updated pom files with the new snapshot (or maybe the release to be tagged, no idea).

I see that the message clearly says that user git@github.com has no rights to commit.

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project spring-boot-email-build: Unable to commit files
Error:  Provider message:
Error:  The git-push command failed.
Error:  Command output:
Error:  git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
Error:  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Error:  
Error:  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
Error:  and the repository exists.
Error:  -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

What should I configure in GitHub? I'm the organization admin.

Comment: U r using https or ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had to add the following configs in the maven-release-plugin

```xml
<configuration>
  <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
  <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
</configuration>
```